# Undefined reference on regex.h method

Tags: regex, dev-c++

I downloaded a setup file (.exe) for installing and/or extracting `regex.h` header files and libraries. I think it's `pcre`. I already added the paths in libraries, binaries and C includes in the Compiler Options.

But this error keeps on showing when I compile. 
`undefined reference to _imp__regexec`

EDIT:
This is the code I tried to run.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<regex.h>
#define MAX_MATCHES 1
void match(regex_t *pexp, char *sz)
{
    regmatch_t matches[MAX_MATCHES]; //A list of the matches in the string (a list of 1)
    //Compare the string to the expression
    //regexec() returns 0 on match, otherwise REG_NOMATCH
    if (regexec(pexp, sz, MAX_MATCHES, matches, 0) == 0) {
        printf("Matches.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\"%s\" does not match\n", sz);
    }
}
int main()
{
    //for regex
    int regexRes = 0;
    regex_t exp;
    //open syntax file
    FILE * syntax;
    syntax = fopen("syntax2.syntax", "r");

    getch();
    fclose(syntax);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like you're not linking the library - what do your linker options look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I added the library in the Compiler Options of Dex-C++. `C:\pcre\lib`

Comment: You mean the linker commands? What should I write there? It says: `-static-libgcc`

Comment: at a guess I would add -lregex to the linker commands

Comment: `cannot find -lregex` Thanks for suggesting though.

Comment: Update: I got it. I just added a `-lpcre`. Thanks.